# Loading csv for Kafka with Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm tring to load and assign randomly to topics(5 topics) information from csv file.
This is my current code. How do get this working?

```
pconf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': brokers,
    'partitioner': 'random',
    'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8')
}

producer = SerializingProducer(pconf)
now = datetime.now()
```

current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

```
f = open('data.csv', 'r')
with f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            for row in range(1000):
                producer.produce(random.choice(topics), value=row)
                sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.stderr.write('%% Aborted by user\n')
        except BufferError:
            sys.stderr.write('%% Local producer queue is full (%d messages awaiting delivery): try again\n' % len(p))
```

I'm getting error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

Comment: If you want to load CSV data into Kafka there are better ways, namely, Kafka Connect: https://rmoff.dev/csv-into-kafka

Comment: Your usage of `row` seems to be confusing as your are using it twice in both for loops.